# Managing users access with google identity platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

This is a pretty general question although I can't seem to find an easy way to manage it. Basically I've set up a Google Cloud Platform Identity platform and have created a mock user. I'm signing into the user via the API.

`https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=......`

However the token returned doesn't have scopes or permissions to access any google services. I'm then trying to access the sheets api and can't because the users permissions don't have access.

I'm wondering is there a way to give a firebase user on identity platform access to GCP api's like sheets so they can create and view specific spreadsheets.

I had previously attempted to use an API Key just and handled my own authentication/authorisation but then I couldn't control granular access to the google sheets web pages.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the application you are using? Are you using solely the REST API for authenticating? Or are you using the web SDK? With the Web SDK, you are able to add scopes to the authentication providers as shown in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/google#signing_in_users_with_the).

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm using the API and the Web SDK. I'm using the web sdk for a UI which will control users access via oauth (identity platform) and I'm using the API via my server which is also protected by the oauth server. Basically the JWK uri points to the firebase authentication server provided by Identity platform. What I'm trying to do is access google sheets both through the API (creating sheets for a specific subset of users) and then access the sheets via googles URI - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/spreadsheetId/edit#gid=0

Comment: If you are trying to use the API from a server side application, you can [try the Admin SDK](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/concepts-admin-auth-api) for Identity Platform.Otherwise the OAuth documentation also has a guide for passing scopes when [authenticating users in a web app through the REST API](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#creatingclient). Is this what you were using already?